# Naming conventions around internationalization

Tags: language-agnostic, internationalization, naming

I am currently trying to internationalize my application. Despite reading some documentation or looking at source code, I am still not sure about naming standards/conventions around internationalization. (Excuse me if some of the points bellow are obvious, I am not a native English speaker)

I feel that i18n is an old topic in Computer Science so it must have at least some conventions. That's why I'd prefer to use the right names for my code, documentations and further research.

Here are some specific points :

#### Languages identification

I plan to differentiate the different languages with tags of the form `en-US`, `en-GB`, `fr-FR`, etc. (I've seen those in lots of places like Mozilla's code or during the Debian installation).

Does this format has a designation ?
Do the variables containing those tags have dedicated names ?
Is this a "locale" ? (this word seems to come a lot but is a bit vague) Like, is `var locale = "en-US";` the way to name it ?

#### Translation Tables

For each language, I want to store translation as a key-value pairs table between the name used in the code and the string with the actual translation.

In example, for `fr-FR`:

```
| key          | value    |
|--------------|----------|
| action.reply | répondre |
| action.edit  | éditer   |
| action.hide  | masquer  |
| ...          |          |
```

Is there a name for the `key` ? I've seen "languageId", "key" or "entity".
Is there a name for the `value` ? What's the best: `translation`, `localizedString`, something else ?
Is the value a "locale" ? Or maybe the whole table ?

At least, I get one thing: those tables should be stored in a directory called `locale` or `locales` (I prefer the plural form used by Mozilla, but angular-translate (a JS lib) uses singular...)

#### Objects

The translation table above might be enough for static parts of the UI, but I also have to allow users to optionally translate some of the content they submit. So I have to answer the following needs :

- Given a language, get the translation for the content internally labelled `foo`
- Given a content internally labelled `bar`, get the translation for a language

In the second case, the object holds information only for one specific content. It represents one "thing" as opposed to the translation tables. Is there a distinction in the names of those structures (each of them suitable to retrieve data in a different way) ?
How should these "accessors" be called ?

#### Locale

The usage of this word really puzzles me. Even after looking for translation or reading code, I can't figure out exactly what people mean when they use it.

#### Note

I'm aware that this question about naming conventions can lead to some subjective or "name it as you feel it" answers so I would really appreciate if **your answers are backed by some examples**.

(In case you're wondering, my application is written in JavaScript but the question is rather language agnostic)

Comment: Since this isn't a full answer, I'll leave it as comment. The `en` part of `en-US` comes form ISO 639 standard for langauge codes: https://www.loc.gov/standards/iso639-2/php/code_list.php while the `US` part of comes form ISO 3166 standard for country codes: http://www.iso.org/iso/country_codes. Together they form what is known as the IETF language tag as specified by RFC5646 and RFC4647. Otherwise commonly known as "locale"

Comment: Locale specifies two things - language and country. There are some weird locales like "C" which simply says: behave like a traditional C compiler would. Using the two things you can derive other things like weather 1/2/2015 means first of February (English) or second of January (American) 2015, what the default currency should be etc.

Comment: @slebetman thank you for your comment. I also searched for more info (ie: I learned about gettext) I understand now that "locale" simply describes the language to use and by extensions its language tag and related tables but I'm still not sure about the rest. Maybe I have "too high expectations" about conventions even if i18n is an old problem.